# Android call ViewModel from Background Service / Room

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack

1) How can I access/change a ViewModel (of the MainActivity for example) from a background service, or how can I set an observer on a LiveData element from a service?

2) My UI should be observed when a special table in the database got a new element (Because a Background Services inserts new messages which should be shown in the active view - for example a chat). Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You should not change the ViewModel from a background service, Instead you should have a LiveData Instance in your ViewModel and you should just update the LiveData from your service

Comment: I will try this